# removing image loading time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen what I consider a design flaw on a few websites recently but I'm not sure how you would go about correcting it. The flaw usually occurs in websites that hold lots of images. For example a website with a gallery.

The design flaw is when you click on a webpage the page opens and you then watch the images slowly load onto the screen. I really don't like the look of this as it looks quite cheap. However, I don't understand how I would go about preventing it from happening.

It would be great if someone could explain to me the logic behind the problem and a nudge in the right direction for finding/learning the solution.

Comment: Are you referring to sites that don't preload their images?

Comment: Buy a faster internet connection, or you could use a preloader overlay and remove it via `window.onload`

Comment: Is it some kind of lazy loading? You know that people will not wait more than about 5 seconds for a website to load right? you could add a loading icon and load the image on the background (once loaded it could just appear at once on the screen).

Comment: The site should display what is called "thumbnails" or version of images of much reduced dimension and size which loads much faster. When you click the thumbnail - full-sized image is loaded

Comment: Maybe the big version of the image is bigger that what you need, in quality or dimension and the data to download are too much

Answer (score 1):

Just an example, but if you wanted to hide the page until it is ready, you could add an overlay div that blacks out the page:

```
.overlay {
  background: #000; 
  height:     100%; 
  width:      100%;
  z-index:    999;
  top:        0; 
  left:       0; 
  position:   fixed; 
}
```

Then once the whole page has loaded remove it with jQuery:

```
$('document').load(function() {
    $('.overlay').remove();
});
```

---

EDIT: Alternatively you could identify all the images you intend to display as a server-side process, then find the average colour or something, and return that as a stand-by background for the container of each img. That's going to be pretty server intensive if you're not storing that data. It's entirely up-to-you really, it's a design choice.